# VBA: Coordinate batch jobs between several computers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba script that extract information from huge text files and does a lot of data manipulation and calculations on the extracted info. I have about 1000 files and each take an hour to finish.

I would like to run the script on as many computers (among others ec2 instances)  as possible to reduce the time needed to finish the job. But how do I coordinate the work?

I have tried two ways: I set up a dropbox as a network drive with one txt file with the current last job number thart vba access, start the next job and update the number but there is apparently too much lag between an update on a file on one computer is updated throughout the rest to be practical. The second was to find a simple "private" counter service online that updated for each visit so han would access the page, read the number and the page would update the number for the next visit from another computer. But I have found no such service.

Any suggestions on how to coordinate such tasks between different computers in vba?

Comment: I appriciate all answers but that said, we all know the limitations of scripts like vba compared to programming languages but sometimes you need to use what you have and thats why i tagged this with excel-vba. So I especially appriciate answers that adress how to share small pieces of information between instances of Excel on different computers in real time and less so answers that want to rewrite my script from scratch

Answer (score -3):

First of all if you can use a proper programming language, forexample c# for easy parallel processing.

If you must use vba than first optimize your code first. Can you show us the code?

Edit:
If you must than you could do the following. First you need some sort of fileserver to store all text files in a folder.

Then in the macro, foreach every .txt file in folder,
try to open the first in exclusive mode if the file can be opened, then ("your code" after your code is finished move the file elsewhere) else Next .txt file.